# Function to generate all valid parentheses of n*2

Tags: java, algorithm

For a leetcode [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/) to generate the valid parentheses of length 2n, I have written this solution. It is working for smaller inputs but not for larger inputs. Please suggest a way to optimise my code.

I have read the [Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413881/understanding-function-to-generate-parentheses/23414519) but was unable to implement the same concept in my code.

```
 //I have writte a bruteforce approch and got all the possible combinations..
//Then filter all the combinations to check if every one of them is a valid combination



public class Solution {



    public ArrayList<String> generateParenthesis(int a) {

        ArrayList<String> allCombinations = getAllPossibleCombinations(2*a,new ArrayList<String>());
        ArrayList<String> prunedCombinations = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        for(String comb : allCombinations)
        {
            if(isCombinationValid(comb))
            {
                prunedCombinations.add(comb);
            }
        }

        return prunedCombinations;
    }

    //Bruteforce way to get all the combinations...
    public ArrayList<String> getAllPossibleCombinations(int num,ArrayList<String> presentCombinations)
    {
        //templist is used to populate the result and pass the values
        ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(num == 0) //num is zero, so return the combinations
        {
            return presentCombinations;
        }
        else
        {
            //In first call, just add ( and )
            if(presentCombinations.isEmpty())
            {
                tempList.add("(");
                tempList.add(")");
            }
            else //From second call, add ( and ) for current values in stack
            {
                for(String presentComb : presentCombinations)
                {
                    tempList.add(presentComb+"(");
                    tempList.add(presentComb+")");
                }
            }
        }
        //To pass the intermediate values and num-1
       return getAllPossibleCombinations(num-1,tempList);
    }


    //Check if an individual combination is valid..
    //Use stack to match the paranthesis
    public boolean isCombinationValid(String comb)
    {
            Stack<Character> st = new Stack<Character>();

            for(int i=0 ; i < comb.length() ; i++)
            {
                char current = comb.charAt(i);
                if(current == '(')
                {
                    st.push('(');
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!st.isEmpty() && st.peek() == '(')
                    {
                        st.pop();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        st.push(')');
                    }
                }
            }

            if(st.isEmpty())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

    }


}
```

Comment: Just stick like glue to the definition of _well-formed parentheses expression_ (empty, prefixed, suffixed, surrounded) and use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `isCombinationValid`

> ```
>           for(int i=0 ; i < comb.length() ; i++)
>           {
>               char current = comb.charAt(i);
> ```

Since you never use `i` for anything other than generating `current`, you could just

```
          for (char current : comb.toCharArray())
          {
```

This way you wouldn't have to manage `i` at all.

> ```
>         if(st.isEmpty())
>         {
>             return true;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
> ```

This is more complicated than need be.

```
        return st.isEmpty();
```

This has the same result in seven fewer lines.

> ```
>             if(current == '(')
>             {
>                 st.push('(');
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 if(!st.isEmpty() && st.peek() == '(')
>                 {
>                     st.pop();
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     st.push(')');
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Instead, you can say

```
            if (current == '(')
            {
                st.push('(');
            }
            else if (st.isEmpty())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                st.pop();
            }
```

You know that anything in the stack must be a `'('`, so you don't need to `peek` to check.  And if you ever find an extra `')'`, you can quit immediately.  You already know that it's not well-formed.  So if the first character is a `')'`, you don't even have to go through the rest of the string.

I prefer not to use an `else` with an `if !`.  I just find the logic easier to follow this way.  And I switched to the more common `else if` rather than

#### `getAllPossibleCombinations`

> ```
>         if (presentCombinations.isEmpty())
>         {
>             temp.add("(");
>             temp.add(")");
>         }
>         else //From second call, add ( and ) for current values in stack
>         {
> ```

You are doing this with each recursive call, but that's not necessary.  Rather than do this in `getAllPossibleCombinations`, replace

> ```
>         ArrayList<String> allCombinations = getAllPossibleCombinations(2*a,new ArrayList<String>());
>         ArrayList<String> prunedCombinations = new ArrayList<String>();
> ```

```
        for(String comb : allCombinations)
```

with

```
        List<String> initialCombinations = new ArrayList<>();
        initialCombinations.add("(");

        List<String> prunedCombinations = new ArrayList<>(); 
        for (String comb : getAllPossibleCombinations(2*a, initialCombinations)))
```

You don't need the `")"` one at all, because no valid version can start with a closing parenthesis.

I also changed your use of `ArrayList<String>` as the variable type to just use `List<String>`.  Unless you use some functionality specific to `ArrayList`, it is generally better to use the interface (`List`) rather than the implementation (`ArrayList`) as the type.  This makes it easier to change the implementation in the future.

I also changed the right hand side to use the newer `<>` notation.  It's possible that your Java doesn't support that.  If so, just leave it as `<String>`.

One might argue that this makes `getAllPossibleCombinations` less reusable, as you have to pass a specific opening parameter.  This is true, but it was also true of your original.  To get around this, you can specify a version that does not require a `List` to be passed:

```
    public List<String> getAllPossibleCombinations(int maximumPairCount) {
        List<String> initialCombinations = new ArrayList<>();
        initialCombinations.add("(");

        return getAllPossibleCombinations(maximumPairCount - 1, initialCombinations);
    }
```

Now you could declare the two parameter version `private`, as all consumers should call this version instead.  And you can get rid of your `isEmpty` check, as it will never be called that way.  This won't shorten your code, but it will make it run faster, as you save checking `isEmpty` for nearly every call.

#### Optimization

The code that you link checks for validity as it builds the string.  If you do that, you don't have to save invalid combinations like `"))))"`.  Since there are \$2^{2*n}\$ combinations but only a smaller number of these are valid, this should make your program take longer to run out of memory.

Note that if you do this, you don't return `false` if the stack has extra `'('` in it.  It's valid for a partial expression to have unmatched `'('`.  What's invalid is unmatched `')'`.